# Install samba4.4.4 from source on centos7

Tags: centos, compiling, samba4

Following the steps on [Samba wiki page](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_source), I was able to build the samba source code. However, after `sudo make install`, I could not start the samba service since there is no `systemd` entry under `/usr/lib/systemd/` folder. Am I missing any steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling/installing from source, as with most software distributions like this, the service will not be installed.  You need to do those steps manually (or with configuration management of some type).  Here's an example that I find, specifically for Samba 4 on a systemd based Linux system.

Translating from here: https://dev.tranquil.it/wiki/SAMBA_-_Fichier_systemd_samba4

Create the file `/lib/systemd/system/samba.service` with an editor containing the following:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/usr/local/samba/var/run/samba.pid
LimitNOFILE=16384
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/conf.d/samba
ExecStart=/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run, as root:

```
# systemctl enable samba
# systemctl start samba
```

If you have errors when starting, check the logs as indicated with"

```
# journalctl -xe
```

Comment: That is very helpful! However after I did that, I get some errors starting the service: "You should start smbd/nmbd/winbindd instead for domain member and standalone file server tasks" Clearly I missed some critical steps. Do you have any references so I can follow to make sure samba is up and running? Thank you!

Comment: I later added "sever services = +smb", but still plenty of errors

Comment: You'll want to use the same pattern as the service I helped you create above, to create services for the other daemons that you want systemd to manage for you, smbd/nmbd/winbindd.  Of course, you may not need all of those services, so read documentation and set configs according to the needs of your implementation.  There's a lot of functionality that Samba provides, but you only want to enable what you need.